# SNMP RW on Linux servers

Tags: linux, security, snmp

OK, I've been reading about SNMP misconfiguration security issues and it seems like hackers can actually own a router if they discover its SNMP RW community string via tools like snmpblow and snmpwalk: http://securityreliks.securegossip.com/2011/04/hacking-snmp-in-a-few-simple-steps/

But what about SNMP RW on Linux boxes? How far the bad guys can go with this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"As far as your SNMP configuration and operating system lets them."
This can include executing arbitrary programs (often by taking advantage of net-snmp `exec` directives), altering network / routing configuration (if you do something dumb like run snmpd as root), etc. etc. etc. (it really is a nearly infinite list).

If you care for security the general rule is **do not** enable SNMP "write" access.

If you ***really*** care for security you'll also insist on using SNMPv3.

If you ***really, REALLY*** care about security you won't enable SNMP at all, or you'll lock it down so there's no way to get at it from the public internet.
Even with Read-Only access an attacker can get a metric buttload of valuable intelligence on your system by a simple snmpwalk.  You don't want to make things any easier than they already are.